# TypeScript: extend "this" based on constructor parameters

Tags: typescript, class, types, this

I'm trying to add types to a class which extends "this" in the constructor.
I saw this question [Typescript: extending "this" inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696671/typescript-extending-this-inside-class) but I don't know in advance which object would passed to the constructor.

```
class Baz<T extends object> {
    public test;
    constructor(props: T) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}

interface IFoo {
  foo: number;
}

const p = new Baz<IFoo>({foo: 1});
p.test;
p.foo; // Not recognized.
```

I'm trying to recognize as properties the fields passed as object.

Comment: Please ensure you share code that only has errors related to your actual question. You're missing a type and an initializer on `test`.

Comment: You are right. In fact `test` wasn't really relevant...
It was there just to show that I can access to the property of the class (of course) but not the one assigned in the constructor (`foo`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a constructor and a generic class. You could use a generic type parameter on the class to affect the type of a data member or a method's argument or return type, but not to add features to the class itself.

You can do it with a static method, though (or just a standalone function):

```typescript
class Baz {
    public test: string = "something";

    private constructor() { // If you want it to be private; that's up to you
    }

    static create<T extends object>(props: T): Baz & T {
        const b = new Baz();
        Object.assign(b, props);
        return b as Baz & T;
    }
}

interface IFoo {
    foo: number;
}

const p = Baz.create<IFoo>({ foo: 1 });
p.test;
p.foo; // <== Works fine
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYC9oG8BQ0PQA4FcBGIAlsNAC4CmEpAXNFQE6EB2A5tALzQBEEA9gLblSAC2YsuAblTpMWRgDcwFaMF5MGOYKV70AFAEoU0APTHoASQBm0AJ68c0AO5gmpaITfboectgVLyCTJhJQByGBwsMl5bexkMAF9pTDpSJWIVenIAgB4AFWhyAA8KJgATGF48ACtyLQA+XTleLAhaPP1aeCQAMmgCtBSU1XU3PA5oJnJHOEQDKSHMAHkautIAOkgIQhYmXTwAGj8WiH0Fxegs0hx6Jm9oSFne-vPE1CTUZgp6SzBgX3MADFeDFBphLCDaEwcPwfPQpB8RlRsBNuutgFlckCQY1kNAIbxaABGaAJM6oLDrChUKSUglBUzQHLsTgAdR0AGsYJZmORUEA)

Comment: I'm adding types to an existing javascript codebase.
So the only way is to change the code? I find it a bit unfortunate...

Comment: @user2342561 - Certain patterns people have used in JavaScript don't map well to TypeScript's type system. I'm fairly sure this is one of them. IMHO, what was there was already off semantically -- the code says `new Baz` but what you get back isn't a `Baz`, it's a `Baz + ____`. I don't think TypeScript has a way to express that *using a constructor*. So yeah, you either have to change the code or use a type assertion everywhere you were doing it (`new Baz(/*...*/) as Baz & ____`), which seems like more work.